# How to make a if-else Angular template with only ng-container?

Tags: angular, if-statement, angular-template

I would like to make an if-else statement in my angular template. I started with that :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="contributeur.deb; else newDeb" >
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 1]
</ng-container>
<ng-template #newDeb>
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 2]
</ng-template>
```

And I tried to only use ng-container :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="contributeur.deb; else newDeb" >
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 1]
</ng-container>
<ng-container #newDeb>
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 2]
</ng-container >
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I have this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
    at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:10200:52)
    at NgIf._updateView (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:96), <anonymous>:2013:45)
    at NgIf.set [as ngIfElse] (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:96), <anonymous>:1988:18)
    at updateProp (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:11172:37)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:10873:19)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:12290:17)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:12258:16)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:12887:59)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (eval at <anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:11), <anonymous>:12828:13)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ActionsButtons.html:5)
```

Can anyone explain me what is going wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

[The code for the `ngIf` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L128) expects to be passed a reference to a template ([`TemplateRef`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/core/src/linker/template_ref.ts#L13)) for the else branch, which it will call [`createEmbeddedView`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/bebedfed24d6fbfa492e97f071e1d1b41e411280/packages/core/src/linker/template_ref.ts#L41) on to display the nested content.  Therefore, it makes no sense to try to use any other kind of element for the else content - it just won't work. You're able to nest an `ng-container` *inside* the `ng-template` if needs be, though.

This might seem unintuitive, but bear in mind that [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) (i.e. ones that you call with a `*`) are *always* represented as `ng-template` under the hood, no matter what kind of element they're attached to - these two pieces of code are the same:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="contributeur.deb; else newDeb" >
    ...
</ng-container>
<ng-template #newDeb>
    ...
</ng-template>
```

---

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="contributeur.deb; else newDeb">
    <ng-container>
        ...
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #newDeb>
    ...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading the [Angular docs page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) on Structural Directives - it's long, but really informative.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer.  I spent hours scratching my head trying to solve a null component in a canDeactivate guard.

Comment: @JoeClay Error: src/app/leads/leads-list.component.ts:99:34 - error NG5002: Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at column 7 in [lead; else newDeb] in C:/Users/iii/Desktop/ui-code-challenge-1-master/src/app/leads/leads-list.component.ts@98:33

99             <ng-template [ngIf]="lead; else newDeb">

Answer (score 18):

I do not love the standard Angular structure for **if then else**. Then I found an alternative solution with **ngSwitch**:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="isFirstChoice(foo) ? 1 : (isSecondChoice(foo) ? 2 : -1)">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="1">
    ...first choice...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="2">
    ...second choice...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    ...another choice...
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

To answer to your request I'd use this:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="contributeur.deb && 'isDeb'">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'isDeb'">
    ......
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    ......
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 6):

It bears mentioning that this simple alternative is perhaps more readable than many of the other options. Just using a second ng-container, and just 'not'-ing the condition with an exclamation mark to make the else section.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="contributeur.deb" >
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 1]
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!contributeur.deb">
    [... HERE IS A RESULT 2]
</ng-container >
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular 17, we can use `@if(){}` OR `@if(){} @else if(){}`.
after using this , code looks clear and more readable.

```
@if(contributeur.deb){
   [.....any code]
}
@else {
   [.....any code]
}
```

like that.

Please go through these reference links.

[angular-17-new-control-flow-with-signals](https://www.angularaddicts.com/p/angular-17-new-control-flow-with-signals)

[new-control-flow-in-angular-17](https://medium.com/@ayushgrwl365/introducing-new-control-flow-in-angular-17-89e67903daed)

Thanks

Comment: Control flow indeed solves this issue. For people who are not familiar with it yet, it would be good to add a link to the documentation for further reading. Also the author of the question is looking for an if else, not an if else-if. Maybe you can edit your answer to improve it.